# How to get name of bitmap from MediaStore.Images

Tags: android, android-widget

I am getting bitmaps from MediStore like

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),id,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

My question is how to get name of every picture ( bitmap ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try below code to get the name of the pics and it's folder from the external storage**

```
            String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME };


    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cur = managedQuery(images, projection, // Which columns to return
            "", // Which rows to return (all rows)
            null, // Selection arguments (none)
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME // Ordering
    );

    Log.i("ListingImages", " query count=" + cur.getCount() + "Columns ="
            + cur.getColumnCount() + "" + cur.getColumnName(0) + ""
            + cur.getColumnName(1) + "" + cur.getColumnName(2));

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {


        int bucketColumn = cur
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);


        int dpColumn = cur
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

        do {

            Log.i("Folder Name",cur.getString(bucketColumn));
            Log.i("Pic Name ",cur.getString(dpColumn));
         } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Ooops","No Media Found");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can I filter in quesry to return only images from specified folder /sdcard/test_images ?

Comment: try setting uri path to specific folder path and see..or you can start new question buddy..